# Android- intent to SDCARD

Tags: android, notifications, mp3, android-sdcard

I created a status bar notification to let my users know that a song is downloading to their Sd Card. My question is, how can I get it so that when the user click on the notification, it sends them to where the file is stored, in this case the download folder? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android doesn't have a default file browser, so there's no official intent for being sent to a file system location.

You can send an intent (as a guess action view) for the file, and have it opened in the default music player or pop up a menu of choices if there are various things that can handle that.

You can install something like the open intents file browser, and send whatever it defines as the intent for viewing a filesystem location.

Comment: I forgot that android doesn't have a default file browser...I've been using CM7 and it has it haha. So how can I have it opened in the default music player???

Comment: @SergioRa - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application should answer that for you.